# How can I make splash screen wait for computations before navigating to next screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm making a splash screen on flutter and I want to run some computation while displaying the splash screen (with the circular progress indicator running) and after all computation is done I want to run a Navigator.push() to navigate to the home screen. The problem is that flutter never waits for the computations, the workaround I did was adding a future.delayed() to my navigator and wait an arbitrary amount of time until all calculations are done.

The code is like this: (The computations are the models being loaded)

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Do all of this
      final bestModel = Provider.of<BestSellingModel>(context, listen: false);
      final salesModel = Provider.of<SalesModel>(context, listen: false);
      final categoryModel = Provider.of<CategoryModel>(context, listen: false);
      if (bestModel.isLoading) bestModel.getBestSelling();
      if (salesModel.isLoading) salesModel.getSales();
      if (categoryModel.isLoading) categoryModel.getCategories();
      DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
      // And only then navigate to next screen without a pre-established time
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 12), () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainTabs()));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [Color(0xffFBC707), Color(0xffF25D19)],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  width: screenSize.width / 1.8,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/splash_logo.png'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // This needs to keep running while the models are being loaded
                    SizedBox(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      height: 64.0,
                      width: 64.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is an example of model I used:

```dart
class SalesModel with ChangeNotifier{
  List<Product> products = [];
  bool isLoading = true;

  Future getSales() async {
    products = await WooCommerce().getProductsByCategory(categoryId: 58);
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

So, is there a way that makes the splash screen's circular progress indicator run at the same time the models are loaded and navigate to home screen after all models are loaded?

Comment: no, flutter run its code in one thread so you cannot do two things at the same time - for that you have to use `Isolate`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar with login state.
My splash listens to a stream of login states.

```
  void setInProgress(bool value) {
    setState(() {
     _inProgress = value;
    });
  } // of setInProgress
```

In your build method, you can add conditions

```
      if (_inProgress)
        Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      if (!_inProgress)
        Center(

          child: HomeScreenWidget(),
        )
```

Every time I do this, I think I really ought to encapsulate it in a widget.
Also, it the calculation state is more than just a boolean, you can use StreamBuilder that listens for a stream of calculation states.

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of doing this before. Thanks!